# Динамическое обновление SetBackgroundColour в зависимости от значения переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Есть текстовый документ, в котором записаны строки, которые изменяются динамически и в зависимости от текста в файле кнопке присваивается цвет.

На данный момент кнопке присваивается цвет только когда программа перезапускается.

Подскажите как сделать чтобы цвет менялся динамически, т.е. чтобы `btn1.SetBackgroundColour(x)` проверял значение переменной `x` и в зависимости от значения переменной присваивался нужный цвет?

```
def t2():
    Timer(3, t2).start ()
    word = u'1'
    text = open(filepath).read()
    if word in text:
        global x
        x = '#FFFFFF'
    else:
        x= '#00FF00'
    word = u'2'
    text = open(filepath).read()
    if word in text:
        x= '#FF0000'

    word = u'3'
    text = open(filepath).read()
    if word in text:
        global z
        z='#FFFFFF'
    else:
        z='#00FF00'
    word = u'4'
    text = open(filepath).read()
    if word in text:
        z='#FF0000'
t2()


class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):        
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (200,150))  
        panel = wx.Panel(self) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        btn1 = wx.Button(panel,-1,"",size=(20,20)) 
        vbox.Add(btn1,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClicked)
        btn1.SetBackgroundColour (x)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel,-1,"",size=(20,20)) 
        vbox.Add(btn2,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClicked)
        btn2.SetBackgroundColour(z)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox) 

        self.Centre() 
        self.Show() 
        self.Fit()

    def OnClicked(self, event): 
        btn = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()

app = wx.App() 
Mywin(None,  '123') 
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса

Comment: Есть файл в котором 50 строк каждая строка может принимать несколько значений например если значение 1 то цвет #FFFFFF, если 2 то цвет #FF0000. Строки в файле изменяются и соответственно меняется значение переменной `x`. В зависимости от переменной изменяется цвет кнопки`btn1.SetBackgroundColour (x)` Если мы запускаем программу кнопка например белого цвета, но если программа запущена и поменялось значение переменной цвет кнопки не изменяется, есть ли возможность периодически проверять значение `x` и менять цвет кнопки без перезапуска программы?@karvetskiy

Comment: У вас кнопки создаются при инициализации программы. Соответственно, обновляться они будут только при перезапуске. Можно каждый раз при изменении значения переменной присваивать кнопке новый цвет.

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит можно пример? @karvetskiy

Comment: Ниже тоже хорошая реализация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import wx
import random


class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):        
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,150)) 

        self.listColor = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF',
                          '#FFFF00', '#00FFFF', '#FF00FF']
        self.flag = True

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, 1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)                     # 1-секундный интервал


        panel = wx.Panel(self) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.btn1 = wx.Button(panel,-1,"",size=(20,20)) 
        vbox.Add(self.btn1,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClicked)
        self.btn1.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(self.listColor))

        self.btn2 = wx.Button(panel,-1,"",size=(20,20)) 
        vbox.Add(self.btn2,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClicked)
        self.btn2.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(self.listColor))

        panel.SetSizer(vbox) 

        self.Centre() 
        self.Show() 
        self.Fit()

    def OnClicked(self, event): 
        btn = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        print(f"btn=> {btn}")

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        # делай что хочешь каждую секунду здесь
        if self.flag:
            self.btn1.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(self.listColor))
        else:
            self.btn2.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(self.listColor))
        self.flag = not self.flag


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App() 
    Mywin(None,  '123') 
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Функция `t2` периодически проверяет текст в файле в котором примерно 50 строк. Каждая строка может иметь 3 значения, например 1,2,3 и каждому значению соответствует цвет фона, например первая строка имеет переменную `x` и нужно изменять цвет фона 1 кнопки если `x=1` например белый цвет, если `x=2` другой цвет, переменная `x` динамически меняется. Например открываем блокнотом текстовый файл правим первую строку, переменная `x` изменилась цвет фона не изменился. Чтобы цвет фона изменился нужно перезапустить программу, подскажите как сделать чтобы цвет менялся без перезапуска @S. Nick

Comment: @Bonbaron я не могу воспроизвести действия функции `t2`, но вы можете ее вызвать в месте где я указал `# делай что хочешь каждую секунду здесь`.  В функции `t2` в конце добавьте, например `return x, z`.  Получите результат работы `t2` и делайте, например `self.btn1.SetBackgroundColour(x)`. Обратите внимание, объект `btn1` должен принадлежать классу, т.е. надо добавить `self.` и тогда к этому объекту можно обращаться в любом методе класса. Интервал периодической проверки установите какой вам надо.